# Function Accessed by Multiple Threads with Parameter Passed by Reference

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am in vb.net and have a function that will be accessed by multiple threads.  Everything inside the function uses local variables.  However, each thread will pass in its own dataset by reference.

From what I have read the local variables should be no problem, but I think the dataset coming in is a concern.

How should I control access / execution of this function to make sure that it is thread safe?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that by 'dataset' you mean a `System.Data.DataSet`, if your function is only reading from the dataset, then you don't need synchronization in any case since "This type is safe for multithreaded read operations" (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx).

If you're modifying the dataset, then as long as each dataset is a different instance, there should be no problem.

If you're modifying the data and if different threads might pass in a reference to the same dataset, you'll need to synchronize access to the dataset using a `Monitor` (`SyncLock` or `lock` in C#) or some other synchronization technique.

Comment: Your answer makes sense. There must be something that I am doing that is causing a problem. I am getting errors with call stacks and other logged data that make me think that I have some kind of threading problem. I'll provide some more info and see if that helps. One thing I am wondering is if I just need to set my function as Shared.

Comment: I grab the System.Data.DataSet that came in and loop over each row populating local variables, calling methods to get more data from the database, etc. The DataSet may have several hundred rows so it is anticipated to take some time to process.

Comment: @Scott: you may need to post some example code to make clear what's going on.  There are certainly all sorts of issues - some subtle, some obvious - that can crop up with threading.